# Как с помощью лямбд преобразовать строку в коллекцию подстрок, записать значения в карту и сложить значения карты

Tags: java-8, лямбда-выражение

Назначается карта с значениями, соответствующими определенным подстрокам

```java
public class App {

    private static Map<String, Integer> numerals = new HashMap<>();

    static {

        numerals.put("ML", new Integer(10));
        numerals.put("NL", new Integer(9));
    }
```

Для начала разбирается вот такая подстрока

**'1 + 1'**

```java
private static void make(String result) {

        String[] arrStrings = parseStringIntoArr(result);

        boolean isNumeric;

        int resultAddition = 0;


        for (String str : arrStrings) {

            isNumeric = str.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);

            if (isNumeric) {
                resultAddition = resultAddition + Integer.parseInt(str);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(resultAddition);

    }


    private static String[] parseStringIntoArr(String result) {
        Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of(result);
        Stream<String[]> streamStings = stringStream.map(s -> s.split(" "));

        List<String[]> collect = streamStings.collect(Collectors.toList());

        String[] arrStrings = null;

        for (String[] arr : collect) {
            arrStrings = arr;
        }

        return arrStrings;
    }
```

Mожно ли сократить такой код и перевести на **Stream** и **лямбда** полностью, может здесь что-то лишнее есть (просьба пояснить) ?

**второй тип подстроки такой:**

'ML + NL'

```java
  private static void make(String resultRome) {

        String[] arrStrings = parseStringIntoArr(resultRome);
        parseNumerals(arrStrings);
    }


    private static void parseNumerals(String[] arrStrings) {

        List<Integer> collect = null;

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        Map<String, Integer> integerMap = null;

        for (String str : arrStrings) {


            boolean isDigit = str.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);

        romeNumerals.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(str))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection());
.....

       }
        System.out.println(integerMap);
    }
```

Здесь я не понимаю, как разобрать подстроку и сразу сопоствалять значения карты перебором, и сразу же выполнить некторую операцию на данными:

- сложение
- вычитание
- деление
- умножение

И это все сделать **только** с помощью **Stream API** и **лямбда**...

У кого есть идеи с пояснениями...

**Обновление**

Итак, с помощью сообщества вот что получилось:

```java
private static void makeV2(String str) {

        /*- используем лямбда-выражения, чтобы отфильтровать только цифры из этого потока,
         * а лишнее удалить;
         * - str.split(" "); - получаем подстроки из строки, то есть получаем массив подстрок
         * - Arrays.stream(strings); - преобразуем в байтовый поток полученный массив строк
         *  - : - это ссылочный оператор, который указывает на статический метод isDigits()
         * класса NumberUtils из библиотеки apache.commons-lang3;
         *  - метод filter() - получает из потока по очереди, по одному элементу и передает их в
         * метод isDigits(), и если елемент валиден и метод  isDigits() вернет true,
         * тогда элемент остается в потоке, иначе удаляется из потока
         * - mapToInt() - данный метод выполняет преобразование полученного элемента из потока,
         * в тип данных  Integer, испльзуя метод valueOf() из класса-оболочки Integer
         * - sum() - это метод кроме того, что запускает на обработку всю цепочку методов,
         * он также все элементы потока суммирует. */

        int sum = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                .filter(NumberUtils::isDigits)
                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();

        System.out.println(sum);
    }


    /*Обработка аналогично предыдущей, только :
     - .filter(romeNumerals::containsKey) - в поток отбираются подстроки, которые содержаться
     в статической карте numerals, которая ранее была объявлена;
     - .map(numerals::get) - здесь происходит из одного потока, вытаскивание оторбранных элементов из карты
     и составление из полученных значений другого потока, который будет содержать значения Integer.
     - затем из этого нового второго потока у каждого объект Integer, получаем примитивное значение
     - получаем 3-й поток, который будет содержать примитивные значения
     - sum() , а этот метод будет складывать значения полученные из 3-го потока.
    * */
    private static void makeSymbols(String str) {

        int sum = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                .filter(numerals::containsKey)
                .map(numerals::get)
                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();


        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Если в чем ошибся, поправьте...

Использование **reduce**

```java
   Integer integer = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                .filter(numerals::containsKey)
                .map(numerals::get)
                .reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a - b)
                .get();

        System.out.println(integer);
```

или

```java
  Integer integer = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                .filter(numerals::containsKey)
                .map(numerals::get)
                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                .reduce((int a, int b) -> a - b)
                .orElse(0);
```

Comment: Лучше использовать orElse, так как get() может кинуть NPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для первого варианта:

```
int sum = List.of("1 + 1".split(" ")).stream()
        .filter(NumberUtils::isDigits)
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
```

Для второго:

```
int sum = List.of("NL + ML".split(" ")).stream()
        .filter(numerals::containsKey)
        .map(numerals::get)
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
```

Для проверки на число использовал библиотеку:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Данный код работает только в Java 1.9+

Comment: используется только java8

Comment: @skyho, тогда используйте Arrays.stream(result.split(" ")) вместо List.of

Comment: а кроме sum() для вычитания, деления и умножения, какие есть методы ?

Comment: @skyho, для остальных функций используйте reduce. Пример: reduce((i, i1) -> i - i1).orElse(0);

Comment: intStream.reduce( (int a, int b) -> a - b).orElse(0); - я получаю 0

Comment: @skyho, используете этот reduce(0, (i, i1) -> i - i1). Для умножения и деления reduce(1, (i, i1) -> i * i1)

Comment: @skyho в первом случае счетчик берет как основу(первое число) первый элемент массива. В данном случае это 1. Получаем 1-1=0
Во втором случае старт начинаем с заданного 0. Получаем 0-1-1=-2.

Answer (score 2):

Ох, сколько нагородили) Один метод `parseStringIntoArr` заменяется `result.split()`. Вот метод `make` на стримах:

```
private static void make(String result) {
    //Вывести сумму чисел строки
     System.out.println(Arrays.stream(result.split(" "))
                                            .filter(a -> a.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit))
                                            .map(Integer::parseInt)
                                            .reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a + b)
                                            .get());
}
```

Тест:

```
make("111 222 333 я_не_число");
```

Вывод:

> 666

А вот метод parseNumerals:

```
 private static void parseNumerals(String result) {
     //вывести сумму значений, которые соответствуют каждой подстроке(кроме отсутствующих).
     System.out.println(Arrays.stream(result.split(" "))
                                            .filter(substrToNums::containsKey)
                                            .map(substrToNums::get)
                                            .reduce((Integer a, Integer b) -> a + b)
                                            .get());
 }
```

substrToNums:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> substrToNums = new HashMap<>();

static {
    substrToNums.put("MA", 9);
    substrToNums.put("MB", 8);
    substrToNums.put("MC", 7);
}
```

Тест:

```
parseNumerals("MA MB MC MR");
```

Вывод:

> 24

Comment: Если не понятно что-то конкретно - спрашивайте. Думаю, что чтобы понять этот код достаточно знать лямбды и стримы на начальном уровне.

Comment: есть ли ресурс или книга по разборку лямбд и стримов (на русском) с примерами, для того чтобы сложилась полная картина, как с ними работать ? Или вы просто в сети искали обрывки и со временем освоили это ?

Comment: @skyho Освоил здесь: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/9.1.php . Главы 8 и 10. Мне этого хватило. Практика очень помогает.